# Why is there still a macbook air?

Tags: macbook-pro

The new macbook is awesome but, it brings up a question. Why is the macbook air still around if the new macbook is lighter and thinner than the air?

Thanks!

Comment: Just saying this question is just for interest and there may not be a right answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the MacBook is an addition to the product line which I believe is somewhat like a "netbook" and the Air line is somewhere between "netbook" and MacBook Pro line. The MacBook uses a Broadwell Mobile Processor and the Air is using Broadwell i5 and i7 processors. There are many comparisons on the Internet even though the MacBook hasn't been released yet. Here is one example of a comparison. http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/macbook-2015-vs-macbook-air-2015-spec-showdown/

Comment: Sure have a great evening!